# Dense subspace of the space of continuous operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading a paper and wondering the origin of the following statement:

"In the space of continuous operators, the set of differentiable operators is dense."

Does anyone can help where can I find this proof?

Comment: What is your base space? What is your topology? These are important details. Assuming you mean the space $C([a,b])$ of continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$ under the uniform topology, for example, this is a straightforward application of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.